Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined' in Angular 17+
I am getting this error with angular 17 while trying to access Object values in dynamic form.
Please check following code for reference
I am getting error in <p *ngIf="dynamicForm.controls[controls.label].errors[validation.name]"> line
<ng-container *ngFor="let validation of controls.validations">
<mat-error *ngIf="dynamicForm.controls[controls.label].touched && dynamicForm.controls[controls.label].errors">
<p *ngIf="dynamicForm.controls[controls.label].errors[validation.name]">
{{validation.message}}
</p>
</mat-error>
</ng-container>
JSON :
fields = [
{
type: "input",
label: "Username",
inputType: "text",
name: "name",
validations: [
{
name: "required",
validator: "required",
message: "Name Required"
},
{
name: "pattern",
validator: "^[a-zA-Z]+$",
message: "Accept only text"
}
]
}, {
type: "password",
label: "Password",
inputType: "text",
name: "name",
validations: [
{
name: "required",
validator: "required",
message: "Password Required"
}
]
}
];
I am creating dynamic form by providing JSON. All validators should be applied to it and also fields should be created dynamically.
